# What's the difference between buying bitizens from the store and buying from the album?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

What's the difference between buying bitizens from the store or the album?

I've noticed that once I bought a bitizen from the store, he no longer appears in the list and I'm unable to buy him a second time. Also, buying a bitizen this way doesn't seem to unlock that species in the game, even if he does ride on the elevator.

So what is the difference of buying bitizens from the two places?

As you can see from the pics below, the prices are different too... Check out the prices of the Wookie and Ithorian from my album, and then from my store.

From the album:
[image]

From the store:
[image][image]

Comment: That is SO strange!  I've always seen the prices being the same. This is the first time I've seen a difference like that!!!!!

Comment: I just looked at mine. The wookie unlocks for 18 BUX. Different from yours. I think you may have stumbled onto the unlocking order!  The price goes down the closer it gets …. I think it's supposed to do the same in the album, but isn't!  Must be a bug!

Comment: How much is your wookie from the store? 18 bux too?

Comment: 18 Bux in store. 72 in album.

Comment: Let's keep an eye on the price in the store and see if the species do unlock when their prices become lower and lower and in the order from cheapest to the most expensive.

Comment: My thought exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Unless it represents yet another bug in the game, I believe that purchasing from the album unlocks the species as a regular elevator passenger/resident bitizen.

I believe that when you purchase someone from the store, it not only unlocks the species, but also unlocks the ? bitizen.

Until recently, the price in the store was always the same as the album. This seems to have changed. Now the prices in the store are dropping while the album is staying the same.

But, once you have unlocked them in the album or via progression they suddenly appear for sale for 1 Bux in the store.

I think there must be a bug at work in all of this.

Comment: The prices are different, as you can see from the pics I just added to the post.

Comment: I just updated to reflect that!  This is the first time I've ever seen a difference!

Comment: Does that mean if I were to buy from the store, it's just as good as buying the unlock from the album? I once bought a Bith from the store because it was cheaper at only 1 bux there, but it remains unlocked in the album like I mentioned before.

Comment: I wish I knew … this is strange new information.